# Counting the unique values of two combined columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows

```
library(data.table)
library(haven)
df1 <- fread(
    "A   B   C  iso   year   
     0   B   1  NLD   2009   
     1   A   2  NLD   2009   
     0   Y   3  AUS   2011   
     1   Q   4  AUS   2011   
     0   NA  7  NLD   2008   
     1   0   1  NLD   2008   
     0   1   3  AUS   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I want to count the unique values of the combination of `iso`, and `year` (which would be `NLD 2009`, `AUS 2011`, `NLD 2008` and `AUS 2012`, so 4.

I tried `df1[,uniqueN(.(iso, year))]` and `df1[,uniqueN(c("iso", "year"))]`

The first one gives an error, and the second one gives the answer 2, where I am looking for 4 unique combinations.

What am I doing wrong here?

(as I am doing this with a big dataset of strings, I would prefer no to combine the columns, then test).

Comment: Your first attempt (`df1[,uniqueN(.(iso, year))]`) is wrong because `uniqueN` 's first argument should be an atomic vector or data.frame/data.table but the actual argument you passed to it is a list (`.(iso, year)`); and in the second case, you passed an atomic vector with two distinct elements (`c("iso", "year")`) instead of the data on which you want to compute the unique values

Comment: Please study the help text: `uniqueN(x, by= `; `x`: A `data.table`; `by`:
`character` or `integer` vector indicating which combinations of columns from `x` to use for uniqueness checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it as follows using `data.table` package.

```
df1[, uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols=c("iso", "year")]
```

or

```
uniqueN(df1, by=c("iso", "year"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the `data.table` approach, `count` from `dplyr` does it very nicely:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% count(iso, year)
```

Output:

```
   iso year n
1: AUS 2011 2
2: AUS 2012 1
3: NLD 2008 2
4: NLD 2009 2
```